# Force Server to Change Load Average

Tags: linux, web-server

Recently we got a server with Limestone Networks to operate as a worker in our web-cluster.

The main infrastructure behind the cluster (being the database and load balancer) are located in Phoenix NAP in Phoenix, Arizona with the new worker being in Dallas, Texas.

After messing around with routing we were able to reduced latency between the boxes to 28ms, the problem is that that is still too high to get any kind of acceptable page load times between the load balancer, the worker in Dallas, and the database.

Our load balancer is based on load averages of the server serving the data. While we still want our server in Limestone to be operating as a backup for redundancy, allowing pages that don't *need* to be served on it to get served from it will slow things down. So we want to force it's load average to say, 10, so that the load balancing system only allows it to serve pages if either the rest of the workers go down or the load on them is so high that they would result in even slower page loading.

I've done my research on this and the best I can come up with is creating a separate load average file (since Linux is really just files) and pulling the data from there, however, we cannot do that because we are using an off the shelf load balancer (Litespeed).

Comment: You gave us your latency figure - that's only half the story. You're saying you have a vehicle that can go 200MPH, but you don't tell us if it's a sport bike or a truck. (What's the bandwidth between the two sites? What kind of throughput do you get when you test the connection? Is there packet loss?)

Comment: You should be aware that database queries are almost completely dependent upon network latency which is the problem here. Regardless to pleasure you - we can transfer at about 500Mb/s between the sites and generally transfer at about 10Mb/s during normal usage. 0% packet loss.

Comment: That's true, and if you were saying 200ms I would say that's definitely an issue, but if 28ms of latency is enough to render your app's performance "unacceptable" you should really be looking at other potential factors (e.g. how many queries/page? Can you consolidate and/or cache?) - You may also want to consider a DB mirror at the remote site if your app is very complex or intertwined - that also buys you some DR capability (and depending on your bandwidth pricing might even save some money).

Comment: Yes this was exactly what I was thinking. (Referring to the database mirror) - being that the application is off the shelf (Multicrafft and WHMCS) we don't have very much control over the queries made. The other problem is it has to poll game-servers themselves in the Phoenix DC so I hope that the database is the only issue. Time to go  work on replication.

Comment: I should also mention that we have *extremely* high performance standards. 3 second load times for us are unacceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Faking" load average completely ignores (in fact, flagrantly violates) [the principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).  Load Average is an important metric, and it should ***NEVER*** be a lie.

The only feasible way to do what you're asking would be to hack a custom kernel that adds a static value (or a sysctl tunable value) to the real load average.
This wouldn't be a terribly complex hack, but the fact that you would have to be mucking about in the kernel should tell you it's probably not the Right Thing To Do.

---

What you really want to do (and what you're indirectly asking to do by faking the load average) is *weight* the remote server so that it isn't used unless it has to be.
I don't know if Litespeed can do that (their online documentation is *awful*), but if it can't you should replace it with a load balancer that can (haproxy, or really *any* decent load balancing software).
This is pretty basic functionality for a load balancer.  Any one worth using should be able to do it.

If you can't weight the server in Lightspeed and you can't change load balancing solutions your other option is to have the remote server simply not answer requests unless the main servers are all down.
Run a process on the remote server that tests the others, and only start your app if the other servers are slow.
<sup>There are a lot of potential pitfalls with this solution which I'm not going to go into - you know your app and can assess how sane this option is for your particular environment. It's main benefit is that you're not mucking about in the kernel.</sup>

Comment: Yeah, I figured going with a different load balancer would be the best bet in this situation, but like you mentioned that in it of itself comes with a bunch of pitfalls since we're primarily sticking to the Litespeed infrastructure.

Comment: It's entirely possible Litespeed's LB supports server weighting (or they would add the feature if you make enough noise) -- If they take the load balancer functionality seriously I can't imagine they wouldn't have that capability.

Comment: They don't, which is sad. It hasn't been updated in years.